# If A is a (mxn) matrix, show that A=0 if (x^t)Ay=0 for any vector x in Rm, y in Rn

Tags: matrices, vectors

If $A$ is a ($m\times n$) matrix, show that $A=0$ if $(x^t)Ay=0$ for any vectors $x\in \Bbb R^m$, $y\in \Bbb R^n$

Comment: Show your some efforts

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=(a_{jk})$, let $e_1,....,e_n$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and let $f_1,...,f_m$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^m$ .

Then compute $f_k^tAe_j.$

Answer (score 1):

Just use the fact that if $e_n$ is the nth vector of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $e_i^T A e_j = A_{ij}$